# How to display only the rows where number of unique values in one column equals value in second column

Tags: mysql, sql

(Using mysql 5.0)

I have this table:

```
opportunity main_user_id certificate_id required_certificates

          1          491              1                     2
          1          341              1                     2
          1          161              1                     2
          1          161              2                     2
          1          205              2                     2
          1          578              2                     2
          2          161              2                     2
          2          466              3                     2
          2          466              2                     2
          2          156              2                     2
          2          668              2                     2
          3          222              5                     1
          3          123              5                     1
          3          875              5                     1
          3          348              5                     1
```

I need to only display the rows where number of distinct values in `certificate_id` equals value in `required_certificates`.

`opportunity_id` column has id's from 0 to 15 and `main_user_id`'s repeat (hence I can't use `group by`)

The table is basically a list of users matched for particular job opportunity, who have the required certificates. All i need to do now, is to only show the ones who have both of the required certificates, not one OR another.

My current sql statement:

```
select op_main.id as opportunity_id,  u.id as main_user_id, c.id as certificate_id, required2.required as required_certificates

from opportunities as op_main
join opportunity_certificates as oc on oc.opportunity_id = op_main.id  
join certificates as c on c.id = oc.certificate_id and oc.is_required
join user_certificates as uc on uc.certificate_id = c.id
join users as u on u.id = uc.user_id

join (

    select id as op_id, (
      select count(distinct c.id) 
     from opportunities as op
     join opportunity_certificates as oc on oc.opportunity_id = op.id  
     join certificates as c on c.id = oc.certificate_id and oc.is_required
     join user_certificates as uc on uc.certificate_id = c.id
     join users as u on u.id = uc.user_id
     where uc.certificate_id = oc.certificate_id and oc.is_required and op.id = op_id
    ) as required from opportunities

 ) as required2 on required2.op_id = op_main.id

where uc.certificate_id = oc.certificate_id and oc.is_required and op_id = op_main.id
```

based on the table above the output would be:

```
    opportunity main_user_id 

          1          161    
          2          466    
          3          222    
          3          123    
          3          875    
          3          348
```

I spent many hours trying to work it out. If someone is keen on helping me, I can send you the database. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please put an example based on your table of the output that you expect? This part ("the rows where number of distinct values in certificate_id equals value in required_certificates"), which seems the key part of your question, is misleading

Comment: ...when grouped by main_user_id

Comment: Posted expected output and extra info. The above table already shows ONLY the users who have matched with each opportunity, but might only have one of the required certificates. In the example table you have 2 rows for user 161 because he has certificate 1 and 2 and opportunity requires 2 certificates, which makes him the only match as other users only have one of the required certificates

Comment: which version of mysql you are using??

Comment: I'm using version 5.0

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I modified the example table and output, I hope this is better.

Comment: I can only refer you to my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple with [windowed functions - MySQL 8 and above](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT certificate_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS cnt
   FROM (
         -- your query with joins
         ) sub
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = required_certificates;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3kWsqnUGfrawv7LAgcS4Jw/0)**

It turns out that `MySQL 8.0`  doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT ...) OVER` so I used subquery with `DISTINCT`.

> ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support '(DISTINCT ..)'

Comment: if the OP don't use MySQL 8  .. with cte si not available

Comment: @scaisEdge Windowed functions/CTE are part of MySQL 8.0

Comment: @scaisEdge Windowed functions are finally available in MySQL.

Comment: starting form which version .. ?

Comment: @scaisEdge Just click link with doc from my answer :)

Comment: I don't think I can use 8.0 unfortunately

Comment: as .. in my comment  .. mysql with windowed  function is available with version 8  not for the most common 5.x  .. actually 5.7  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Fair enough.  I just wanted to point out how simple it could be https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3kWsqnUGfrawv7LAgcS4Jw/0

Comment: @lad2025 thanks  .. i'm agree with you  ..   i know the power  of windowed function  ..but the OP just use mysql 5.0  ..  and the query seems too complex to me for write a  subselect based solution  .,.